# Laravel avg review by product id

Tags: php, laravel

So I have 2 tables:

```
1. Products - id, title, description, price, category
2. Reviews with id, user_id, rating, product_id
```

I'm trying to develop a shop. So, in each product page I have a form where users can submit a review, giving 1-5 stars. On the index page, where all products are displayed with title, description, category, price, I want to display the average rating of each product. I already setup the relationships as follows:

```
Products -> hasMany(review)
Review -> belongsTo(user)
Review -> belongsTo(product)
User -> hasMany(review)
```

How do I interogate the database and display the average rating for each product on index? I found some solutions around here but I couldn't make it work.
P.S: Everyting that is inserted in the Review table is correct, I just need to display it for each product. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your work..

Comment: Should be something like Product->reviews->avg('rating')

Comment: @twothreebrent I get 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: what is the output of `$product->reviews` ? if its empty then whether there is a problem in the relationship or no reviews are set for that particular product

Comment: @Sletheren it returns the entire table content `[{"id":2,"created_at":"2017-09-07 12:22:07","updated_at":"2017-09-07 .... etc`

Comment: @Hades2x then the solution below has to work.

Comment: @Sletheren How I'm supposed to use it? I'm pretty new to laravel. I add it as a function in product controller? I'm confused.

Comment: show me the function you execute now.. so i can integrate the code with what u got

Comment: `public function getIndex()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        
        return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products ]);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Eloquent, it will be something like this, can you make sure it outputs something?

```
$reviews = Product::find($id)->reviews;
$avg = 0;
foreach($reviews as $rev){
 $avg += $rev->rating;
}
return round($avg/count($reviews));
```

With Eloquent, it will be like:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$avg = $product->reviews()->avg('rating');
return $avg;
```

Comment: It works with your Eloquent version. Thank you so much!